# Bind a List<string> to a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list of strings.
I wanna populate a combo box with a list of strings. how do I do this?
All my tries and searchs are dead end.

i used:

```
<ComboBox  Name="comboBox2" ItemsSource="{Binding Combobox2items}" />
 public partial class EditRule : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Combobox2items { get;  set; }

    public EditRule()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Combobox2items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    Combobox2items.Add("DFd");

    }}
```

EDIT:
adding `Combobox2items.ItemsSource = Combobox2items;` 
works, but why ItemsSource="{Binding Combobox2items}" doesn't?

Comment: Bind your list to comboBox.ItemsSource

Comment: Answering to your edit: Binding won't work because Binding takes the property "Combobox2Items" in your current DataContext. But as far as i can see, you never set any DataContext. I suggest you read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can popuplate a ComboBox, in fact every ItemsControl, in 2 Ways.

First: Add directly Items to it, which works in Code or in Xaml

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Item1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Name="Item2" />
</ComboBox>
```

but this is rather static. 
The second approach uses a dynamic list.

As an example, lets assume you have a window and a combobox in your xaml. The Combobox gets `x:Name="myCombobox"`

In your code behind you can create your List and set it as an `ItemsSource`

```
List<string> myItemsCollection = new List<string>();
public Window1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   myItemsCollection.Add("Item1");
   myCombobox.ItemsSource = myItemsCollection;
}
```

this works fine, but has one problem. If you change the List after you set it as an ItemsSource, the UI will not catch up with the newest change. So to make that work aswell, you need to use an `ObservableCollection` now the collection can notify any changes, which the UI will listen to. and automatically add the new item to the combobox.

Answer (score 6):

Any list-based control in WPF has an `ItemsSource` property that you can assign or bind a list to. In code:

```
comboBox1.ItemsSource = myList;
```

... or if your list is a property on an object which is the DataContext for your Window:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" />
```

Comment: that's exactly what I did:   
<ComboBox  Name="comboBox2" ItemsSource="{Binding Combobox2items}" />
 public partial class EditRule : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Combobox2items { get;  set; }
        public EditRule()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Combobox2items = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        }}

Answer (score 5):

Use `ObservableCollection<string>` instead of `List<string>`, it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` for you

[ObservableCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)

> WPF provides the ObservableCollection class, which is a built-in
>   implementation of a data collection that implements the
>   INotifyCollectionChanged interface

Comment: I think the answer is not sufficient. While yes, it would be good practice to use an ObservableCollection. This is not the problem. Its perfectly fine to use an List, if live changing is not wanted or needed. But the question is pretty vague.